# Rigor in proving continuity of $f$ over a closed interval $I$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

Given a function $f$ on a closed interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, where $I = [a,b]$, to prove continuity of $f$ over the interval $I$, what is generally done is the following.

#### 1. We prove that $f$ is continuous at endpoint $a$

$$ \lim_{x \ \to \  a^{+}} f(x) = f(a)$$

#### 2. We prove that $f$ is continuous $\forall c \in (a, b)$

$$ \lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c) \ \ \ \ \text{,}\ \ \ \ \forall c \in (a, b)$$

#### 3. We prove that $f$ is continuousat endpoint $b$

$$ \lim_{x \ \to \  b^{-}} f(x) = f(b)$$

---

My question revolves around step 2 of this process. Usually all that is done to prove the continuity of $f$ over the open interval $(a, b)$, is (using the Limit Laws) a simple direct substitution of a variable $c$ denoting an arbitrary number in the open interval, which is basically substituting $c \in (a, b)$ into $f(x)$.

But I don't see why this is mathematically rigorous? Initially I assumed something along the lines of Mathematical Induction would have been used to prove $f$ to be continuous $\forall c \in (a, b)$, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

**Why does just choosing an arbitrary $c$ to represent a number in the interval $(a, b)$, and showing that the chosen $c$ satisfies the given definition of continuity, prove that $f$ is continuous over $(a, b)$**?

I will give an example below to highlight what I'm asking.

---

*Example* : Prove $f(x) = e^{x}$ to be continuous over the open interval $(0, 2)$

*Proof :* Let $c \in (0, 2)$

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x \to c} f(x) &= \lim_{x \to c} e^{x} \\
&= e^{c} \\
&= f(c)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$
$$Q.E.D$$

*(This is how most proofs for continuity of functions over intervals are treated (at least in first-year Calculus courses)*. But this way of proving continuity doesn't seem rigorous to me at all. It does nothing to explicitly state or show that $c$ is an element of the open interval $(0, 2)$ other than the fact that we assume it to be true. I could say 'Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$', and the proof would still hold, even though $f(x)$ is only defined for $c \in \mathbb{R^{+}}, \ \text{where} \ c \neq 0$.

---

Just stating that $c \in (a, b)$ and showing that $lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$, doesn't seem like it proves anything to me, because $c$ doesn't necessarily need to be bounded within that interval, as we have done nothing to *explicitly* show $c \in (a, b)$ other than the fact that we *stated* it or *assumed* it.

I mean using this sort of proof process, I could say let $c$ be an element of any arbitrary interval $R$, and by simply using direct substitution to show that $lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$, I would show that $f$ would be continuous over $R$, even if $f$ contained discontinuities over $R$, which this sort of proof process doesn't take into account at all.

To re-emphazize, what I'm getting at, what I'm trying to say is I could always pick an arbitrary $c$ in any arbitrary open interval $I$, and using the Limit Laws (as used in this way in these sorts of proofs) always prove $f$ to be continuous on $I$ even if  $I \not\subset D$, i.e. the open interval lies outside of the domain of the function.

As a last sub-question, in Real Analysis is there a more rigorous way in which continuity of a function $f$ over a closed interval $I$ is proven? Is there a reason in Real Analysis why continuity of functions over closed intervals is proved in this sort of way? Essentially I'm looking for a deeper understanding of proving continuity of functions over intervals, and I'm sure Real Analysis must have the answers to the questions I'm asking.

Comment: The problem with a "proof" like that is merely that it doesn't say why $\lim_{x \to c} e^x = e^c$, which means that it really hasn't actually proven anything, since this is the main point. Properly proving this would require you to be explicit about what you mean by $e^x$ and to use the formal definition of the limit.

Comment: But if you were careful about these things then the structure you described at the top is fine; to be continuous on all of $(a,b)$ means just to be continuous at *each point* of $(a,b)$ separately. This is precisely just what you get when you take an arbitrary $c$ and prove continuity there.

Comment: That's not a proof at all. It's a pure petitio principii.

Comment: @Ian, I understand, but the problem I have, is that we do nothing to *explicitly* show that the arbitrary $c$ is within the open interval $(a, b)$, we only assume that $c \in (a, b)$

Comment: @Perturbative That's fine. $c$ is introduced as a symbol to represent an arbitrary element of $(a,b)$ in the first place.

Comment: @Ian, I apologize, I wasn't fully clear in my earlier comments, what I was trying to say was, I could always pick an arbitrary $c$ in any arbitrary open interval $I$, and using the Limit Laws as used in these sorts of proofs, always prove $f$ to be continuous on $I$ even if  $I \not\subset D$, i.e. the open interval lies outside of the domain of the function,

Comment: @Perturbative Again, you couldn't expand out the proof of the convergence because you would be writing down $f(x)$ for $x$ not in the domain of $f$, which is a meaningless string of symbols.

Comment: @Ian, Okay I just realized what you're getting at. What you said about the scenario I commented above being a *'meaningless string of symbols'*, cleared my misconception up. That was **exactly** the reason why I asked this question, as to me it seemed like what was being done was just *'mindless substitution'*, without any care for the consequences of it, which bothered me quite a bit. But now you've clarified that misconception I had. Thanks for your help. If you want to combine and summarize your comments into an answer, I will be happy to accept it as the answer to this question.

Comment: @DanielFischer, If you read the comments above you'll see that I cleared up the misconception I had, I just wanted to clarify that the part of the proof that you said was circular was not the part about assuming an arbitrary $c \in (a, b)$, as Ian, has commented that it is fine to do this. Do you agree with what he has said and everything said above?

Comment: Yes, taking an arbitrary $c \in (a,b)$ is fine. The circular thing is "$\lim\limits_{x\to c} e^x = e^c$", since that's the exact thing that needs to be shown.

Comment: Aside: there's no need to treat the endpoints of the interval specially in general. You need to treat them specially if the function is defined piecewise like $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &, x = 0 \\ x\sin \frac{1}{x} &, 0 < x \leqslant 1\end{cases}$$ of course, but not for $f(x) = e^x$.

Comment: @DanielDischer, Okay thanks for clarifying that, but then how would you go about proving $\lim_{x \to c} e^{x}= e^{c}$, as what I posted is exactly how the textbook '*James Stewart: Calculus'*, treats problems of this type. In proofs of this type the textbook would simply say the reason $\lim_{x \to c} e^{x}= e^{c}$, is due to the Limit Laws and thus direct substitution, which constitutes their proof.

Comment: You say that "proofs" as in your $e^x$ example are out there, but where? I've never seen a proof like that. Can you give a reference?

Comment: @Perturbative Are you familiar with the epsilon-delta definition of a limit? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit

Comment: By the way proving that $f(x) = e^{x}$ is continuous for all $x$ is hard (much harder compared to proving that a polynomial $p(x)$ is continuous for all $x$, this polynomial stuff is proven just using limit laws). But for $e^{x}$ you need to choose a suitable definition of $e^{x}$ and then using that definition show that $e^{x}$ is continuous for all $x$. The statement $\lim_{x \to c}e^{x} = e^{c}$ does not hold automatically but it is implied by the fact that $e^{x}$ is continuous. It is not possible to obtain this result just using simple limit laws in obvious manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem choosing a generic point $c \in I$ to check continuity on $I$ because continuity on an interval in defined in that manner. If the steps involved in proving continuity at $c$ also hold if $c$ lies outside $I$ then it is not a problem (your function is continuous outside of $I$ also unless you specifically mention that $f$ is defined only on $I$ and not elsewhere). What is important is to ensure that the steps don't fail for any $c \in I$. Unless the behavior of a function is not highly specific for some specific point we can chose a generic $c \in I$.

It is worthwhile to consider the simple example $f(x) = x\sin(1/x)$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. This means that $f$ is defined for all $x$. I will prove that it is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and then $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = \lim_{x \to c}x\sin(1/x) = c\sin (1/c) = f(c)\tag{1}$$ and hence $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. **This is wrong.**

The equation $(1)$ is not valid when $c = 0$ but at the same time it is valid if $c \neq 0$. Hence using equation $(1)$ you can prove continuity for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$ except $c = 0$. But for $c = 0$ you need to do something different. Moreover we need to understand why $(1)$ is valid for any $c \neq 0$. The reason is that the function $g(x) = \sin x$ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (this requires a proof and it is not difficult) and the function $h(x) = 1/x$ is continuous for all $x \neq 0$ (this is proven using limit laws). Now using these facts and limit laws each step in $(1)$ is justified as long as $c \neq 0$.

What to do for $c = 0$? Well we have $$0 \leq |f(x)| \leq |x|$$ for all $x \neq 0$ (the inequality is true for $x = 0$ also, but it does not matter here). Hence letting $x \to 0$ and using Squeeze theorem we get $$\lim_{x \to 0}|f(x)| = 0$$ This implies (why? prove it via definition of limit) that $$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = 0 = f(0)$$ so that $f$ is continuous at $0$ also.

Answer (score 0):

An elementary function $f$ (as $e^x$) is continuous in each point of the domain (This follow from monotonicity). ***If you know this***, you know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=f(c)$ for every poit $c$ of the domain.
I believe that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x \sin(\frac{1}{x})=0$ because $\sin$ is bounded and $x\rightarrow 0$. If we define $f(0)=0$ we obtain a function continuous in 0.